# How to make admin grid text to skip to next line?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, response

I have admin grid made by using UI component.
One of the columns is comments column.
Comments can be long and text is spreading horizontally in one line and that breaks grid layout. I want to achieve that text, when it reaches end of cell skips to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to switch column content to html and use

```
<br>
```

Example:

```
<column name="products_html">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                    
                </item>
            </argument>   
</column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, but you can resize column width by adding this in your `ui_component`

```
<item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
<item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">300</item>
```

Sample code:

```
<column name="comment">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Comments</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
            <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">300</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Hope you find what you asked :)